# Web3j client is not detecting any transaction or blockchain from geth

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, pending-transactions, java, web3j

I am using `web3j` to listen to transactions and blockchains through `geth`. It seems that none of the subscriptions that I have created to the blockchain or transaction are detecting changes.

I start `geth` like like the following.

```
./geth \
 --fast --cache=512 \
 --rpc --rpcapi personal,db,eth,net,web3 \
 --ws --wsapi personal,db,eth,net,web3 \
 --metrics --verbosity 5 --fakepow
```

My Java code looks like the following.

```
public class App {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    Web3j web3 = Web3j.build(new HttpService(), 100, Async.defaultExecutorService());  // defaults to http://localhost:8545/
    Web3ClientVersion web3ClientVersion = web3.web3ClientVersion().sendAsync().get();
    String clientVersion = web3ClientVersion.getWeb3ClientVersion();
    System.out.println(clientVersion);
    System.out.println(web3ClientVersion.getJsonrpc());

    web3.blockObservable(false).subscribe(block -> {
      System.out.println(block.getBlock().getNumber());
    }, Throwable::printStackTrace, () -> System.out.println("block done"));

    web3.transactionObservable().subscribe(tx -> {
      System.out.println(tx.getHash() + ", " + tx.getGasPriceRaw());
    }, Throwable::printStackTrace, () -> System.out.println("tx done"));

    web3.pendingTransactionObservable().subscribe(tx -> {
      System.out.println(tx.getHash() + ", " + tx.getGasPriceRaw());
    }, Throwable::printStackTrace, () -> System.out.println("ptx done"));

    System.out.println("umm reached the end");
  }
}
```

All I see on the console of my Java app is the following.

```
Geth/v1.6.1-stable-021c3c28/linux-amd64/go1.8.1
2.0
umm reached the end
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you forgot to add sleep statement. Remember, that subscription takes place asynchronously in a different thread of execution to the rest of our program. Also don't forget to make an unsubscribe method call. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect to Geth socket and not HTTP. As you have not provided the socket URL while Web3J.Build, it will map to default values, as per your comment in the code.

Here's the example:

```
WebSocketService socketService=new WebSocketService("ws://127.0.0.1:8546", true);
Web3J web3Socket=Web3J.build(socketService);
```

8546 is default socket port for Geth. If you have changed that while starting Geth, make sure you use that.